# Search for a non absorbing Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

According to the usual definition:
"A Markov chain is absorbing if it has at least one absorbing state,
**and** if from every state it is possible to go to an absorbing state."
(taken for example from [Darmouth College](https://pdf4pro.com/amp/cdn/absorbing-markov-chains-dartmouth-college-4c8ff3.pdf) - slide #3)

Now I am looking for an example of a Markov chain **having** an absorbing state, but **without** the property that, starting from any state, one can reach this absorbing state... (meaning that the chain can't be defined as absorbing).

I'm sorry to say that I have no imagination so as to construct such an example.

Does someone have some? I have to say I would really appreciate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $p(0,1)=p(1,0)=1$ and $p(2,3)=p(3,3)=1$.
This chain with 4 states has an absorbing state at state 3, but is not an absorbing chain because there is no way to get from state 1 to state 3.

**Addendum:** Here is a variant which is a bit less disconnected:
Suppose $p(0,1)=p(1,0)=1$ and $p(2,3)=p(2,1)=1/2$ and $p(3,3)=1$.

Comment: Thanks @Yuval. Really nice. I thought that would have been more complicated. Nevertheless, your example looks very special, as the MC is made of 2 distinct parts; would it have been possible if some link had existed between the 2 parts? This is where I still don't see how we could do it...

Comment: Well, if from any node you could reach the absorbing node, the chain would be absorbing. I added another example. Do you know how to accept an answer?

Comment: Yes. That's the kind of example I was looking for.